# Slickest method for linear interpolation of 10 values with 100 results

Tags: vb.net, math, interpolation, linear-interpolation

I am writing some code to interpolate values between 1000 at each 100 mark and similarly between 10000 at each 1000 mark should the "Known" value change etc.
See the below trial I did in Excel as a test which works well, I think.

[image: Excel table]

I have coded this in Visual Studio and being a bit of a noob as far as VB.Net is concerned (aka not VBA) I have `Dim`'d these values as `Double` as per below:

```
Private Sub Results()

    'Calculate Interpolation Value between yvals(0 to 9)
    Dim interpolValue As Double = (yvals(1) - yvals(0)) / 10
    'etc to yvals(9 - 10)

    Dim Result1100 As Double = yvals(0) + interpolValue
    Dim Result1200 As Double = Result1100 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1300 As Double = Result1200 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1400 As Double = Result1300 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1500 As Double = Result1400 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1600 As Double = Result1500 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1700 As Double = Result1600 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1800 As Double = Result1700 + interpolValue
    Dim Result1900 As Double = Result1800 + interpolValue
    'etc to Result 10,000

End Sub
```

where `yvals(0)` to `(9)` is the user input data and the Result#### is the interpolated data.

Can anyone recommend a slicker way to do this than writing this code out 90 more times?
Researching the subject I have not really seen a neater/slicker way to do this.

Comment: x+=y inside a loop are your results.

Comment: i was thinking this but decided against a loop as i need to send the results into a document after uncertainty's are calculated on each result. So i would need access to all values easily.

Comment: Then simply put it in a list or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite understand what are you trying to do, however, this might give you some tips and tricks:

```vb
Dim dict As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Double)
Dim interpolValue As Double = (yvals(1) - yvals(0)) / 10
Dim result As Double = interpolValue + yvals(0)

For i As Integer = 1100 To 10000 Step 100
    dict.Add(i, result)
    result += interpolValue
Next
```

Now you have a collection of `KeyValuePair` in this dictionary. The `Keys` a collection of `Integer` which contains numbers between 1100 and 10000. The `Values` a collection of `Double` which contains the calculation results. You can get for example the value of the number 3200:

```vb
Dim Result3200 As Double = dict(3200)
```

To iterate through the keys and get their values:

```vb
dict.ToList.ForEach(Sub(kvp) Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key} Value: {kvp.Value}"))
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this then:

```
Dim StartValue As Integer = 385
Dim EndValue As Integer = 697
Dim StepValue As Double = (2000 - 1000) / 100
Dim interpolValue As Double = (EndValue - StartValue) / StepValue

Dim SomeList As New List(Of Double)
For x = 0 To StepValue
    SomeList.Add(StartValue + x * interpolValue)
Next
```

---

Output:

```
385
416.2
447.4
478.6
509.8
541
572.2
603.4
634.6
665.8
697
```